# Auto Increment id in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want Auto Increment ID in SharePoint and ID should be in the form of CZAR1001,CZAR1002,CZAR1003 and so on.

I have tried `=RIGHT(EmpID-LEN(EmpID-4))` this formula but its not giving proper output. Might be due to `EmpID` is single line text type

Comment: It would help you [Using ID Field in Calculated Column in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/id-field-in-calaulated-column-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

**How to achieve an auto-incrementing field in SharePoint**

The only auto-incrementing number field in SharePoint is the built-in `ID` field on every list.

You cannot reliably use the `ID` field in calculated column formulas to produce your own automatically incrementing field; a formula that references the ID field will only recalculate when you edit the calculated column.

As a workaround, you can set up a workflow to copy the `ID` field value to another field, such as a single line of text field, then create your formula based on that field.

**How to use a calculated column to format information from a text field**

You didn't say so explicitly, but I'm assuming that the `EmpID` field in your formula is a text field at the receiving end of a workflow process as detailed above, so that it has a text value based on the `ID` value.

To concatenate a number value with a text value, you can use an ampersand `&` character in your formula.

For example, if your `EmpID` value is 1001 want your calculated column output to be `CZAR1001`, your formula would look like this: `="CZAR"&EmpId`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the item ID for what you are trying to do. The reason is that the item ID is generated after the list item is created.

You can create a workflow that does this for you. I've been using this reliably to generate RMA numbers for months now.

1. Create a list ("Unique Number") and within that list create 2 columns:

   1. `lastNumber` (Number Type)
   2. `nextNumber` (Calculated) Formula: `=lastNumber+1`
2. Create an item in this list (`EmpID`) and assign any value to `lastNumber`.
3. On the list that you want the number to be generated, create a the column (`Employee ID`)that will hold your unique number.(Single line of text)
4. Fire up SharePoint Designer:

   Create a variable (`vNumber`) type integer
    Set your variable to equal `nextNumber` in the Unique Number list
    Then "set Employee ID" to Variable "vNumber"
    Then Update item in list "Unique Number" | column "lastNumber list to equal "vNumber"

This sort of creates a loop that uses the number in `nextNumber` assigns it to your column then shifts `nextNumber` to `lastNumber` and the calculated columns generates our next one.

You can use another calculated column to add the CZAR at the beginning if your Employee ID.

If this is confusing let me know. I'm not very good at explaining things.

Answer (score 0):

Use the title column to do this, not the ID.
In your workflow create a workflow variable type Integer. Then, add an action to calculate value using ID + 1000 and insert value into your variable. 
Then, add action to concatenate Text + variable into Title field.